# United Kingdom 1 week trip

Tags: planning, uk

Im planning to make a trip across UK for 1 week and I would like to visit these places for sure: Cambridge, Stonehenge, Stratford-upon-Avon, Bath, Edinburgh, Lake District, Nottingham.

I do not mind to visit (less desirable than the cities from the first group because visited in the past, but still good options): Liverpool, York, Oxford, Brighton.

I can start the trip from both Leeds or London. I travel by bus (e.g. National Express), what is the best route for me to minimize expenditures (not all cities could be included, but I think 1 city per day is fine and I can travel at night)?

Comment: kidding, right?

Comment: I can't visit all of them, but cities from the first group are more preferable than from the second, and I don't mind  visit some places in one day.

Comment: @IlyaCherevkov You're likely to spend a lot of time in transit rather then enjoying your trip.  May be it would be better to limit the number of places to visit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to modify your itinerary.  Visiting all the places in your first group in a week *might* be possible if you went by air and taxi,  but you would have perhaps an hour in each town; not really worthwhile.

Stratford, Bath and Stonehenge (and Oxford) are close enough to combine into one trip of  three or four days. York and Nottingham (and perhaps Liverpool, travelling by train) could be day-trips from Leeds, as Cambridge and Brighton could from London. Travelling from Leeds to London, via Nottingham, would be a long day.  Edinburgh and the Lake District (as also John O'Groats, Lands End and Anglesey) are out of reach on a trip such as you propose.

Comment: Personally, I would rent a car rather than take the plane or a taxi given how it increases the flexibility (although the OP's comment about the bus might imply he doesn't drive or is on a tight budget). But totally concur with the statements everyone else is making - this itinerary is way too ambitious to actually enjoy your time.

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion about day-trips from London and Leeds is very good - I think I will do that. Rent a car is a good option, but I don't have enough driving experience in left-hand traffic. And you are right, I definitely need to reconsider plan and, perhaps, timescale.

Comment: @Ilya, you'll never get the experience if you don't start some time. It's really not as hard as you think. Us British have to do the opposite all the time when we travel...

Comment: I think you could get a lot more than an hour in each place if you did things by train.